# unable to ingest csv data into algebraixlib

Tags: python, algebraixlib

I'm playing with the hello world example of the algebraixlib and i'm getting a funky error when trying to import sample data

```
import import_csv from sampleData.csv
clan = import_csv(file)
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to import the `import_csv` function from the `csv` module, then you can slurp the CSV file in as a `MathObject` in one line of code.

```py
from algebraixlib.io.csv import import_csv
csv_as_clan = import_csv(file_path_or_file_object)
```

Take a look at https://github.com/AlgebraixData/algebraixlib/blob/master/examples/hello_world.py and notice how lines 181-182 are importing the python module using the `import` keyword. `import_csv` is the function that actually takes a file as an argument and returns a valid `MathObject`.